# PostgreSQL query performing differently on different versions/VMs

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm currently migrating a PostgreSQL database and performance on new infrastructure (v 11.12) is considerably worse than on our current infrastructure (v9.1), with the same data structure.

Query that is being executed:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(ab.uprn) FROM  (select (st_dump(st_setsrid(st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((459879.14 148164.21, 459879.14 148264.21, 459979.14 148264.21, 459979.14 148164.21, 459879.14 148164.21))'),27700))).geom AS geompoly) gp,  os_addressbase.addressbase ab  INNER JOIN os_addressbase.addressbase_geom ag ON ab.uprn=ag.uprn WHERE st_intersects(geompoly,geom) AND NOT st_touches(geompoly,geom)
```

Explain results below:

v9.1

```
"Aggregate  (cost=412.24..412.25 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=3720.697..3720.698 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..412.12 rows=48 width=8) (actual time=297.023..3720.522 rows=23 loops=1)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..227.15 rows=48 width=8) (actual time=174.664..2933.783 rows=23 loops=1)"
"              Join Filter: (_st_intersects(((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry)).geom), ag.geom) AND ((NOT (((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry)).geom) && ag.geom)) OR (NOT _st_touches(((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry)).geom), ag.geom))))"
"              ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=20.678..20.691 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              ->  Index Scan using ix_spatial_addressbase on addressbase_geom ag  (cost=0.00..152.45 rows=145 width=166) (actual time=152.371..2906.931 rows=23 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry)).geom) && geom)"
"        ->  Index Scan using addressbase_os_pkey on addressbase ab  (cost=0.00..3.84 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=34.192..34.196 rows=1 loops=23)"
"              Index Cond: (uprn = ag.uprn)"
"Total runtime: 3721.705 ms"
```

v11.2

```
"Aggregate  (cost=3863931.90..3863931.91 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=5044025.124..5044025.129 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=1758059.87..3839039.08 rows=9957128 width=8) (actual time=5042708.712..5044025.078 rows=23 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: (ag.uprn = ab.uprn)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..1860325.16 rows=9957128 width=8) (actual time=82.458..271.051 rows=23 loops=1)"
"              ->  Result  (cost=0.00..265.26 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.029..0.037 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                    ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.27 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.027..0.034 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              ->  Index Scan using ix_spatial_addressbase on addressbase_geom ag  (cost=0.42..1850.09 rows=996 width=40) (actual time=82.427..270.989 rows=23 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: ((((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry))).geom) && geom)"
"                    Filter: (_st_intersects((((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry))).geom), geom) AND ((NOT ((((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry))).geom) && geom)) OR (NOT _st_touches((((st_dump('0103000020346C00000100000005000000F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE41190241F6285C8F2C131C41E17A14AE21160241F6285C8F9C111C41E17A14AE21160241'::geometry))).geom), geom))))"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=1267817.60..1267817.60 rows=29881348 width=8) (actual time=5042357.051..5042357.052 rows=29881349 loops=1)"
"              Buckets: 131072  Batches: 512  Memory Usage: 3325kB"
"              ->  Index Only Scan using addressbase_os_pkey on addressbase ab  (cost=0.56..1267817.60 rows=29881348 width=8) (actual time=0.035..5000410.264 rows=29881349 loops=1)"
"                    Heap Fetches: 29881349"
"Planning Time: 144.263 ms"
"Execution Time: 5044025.695 ms"
```

Can someone suggest a reason for the different execustion plans? And possible settings changes I can look into? The same indexes and pkey have been applied to both instances.

Comment: I'm not sure that the arbitrary cost units are comparable across versions, try using explain analyze to get the actual times.

Comment: adding parallel to the configuration in 11 might help, also check working memory etc are the same on both instances

Comment: This is less a GIS issue than a RDBMS configuration one; you might be better off asking this over in [dba.se].

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. EXPLAIN updated to include ANALYZE, as you can see vastly different times. I have checked the conf and there are some differences, so thanks for that. I set them at session level and it seemed to downgrade performance even further, so a bit of a puzzle.

Comment: There is also a big difference in the number of rows in the plan. Do you have the same quantity of data in both ? Also try to run `VACUUM ANALYSE` on your tables

Comment: Few hints here... first, as stated above, you should run ANALYSE on tables. It looks like your plans are massively overestimated. Second, 'Intersect and no touches' can be substituted by st_contains. Third, if there is 1 to 1 relationship from addressbase to addressbase_geom and you only want to count them, then there is no reason to fetch and join rows from addressbase table. Just count the number of addressbase_geoms inside polygon and you should be good to go...